# I am getting an error when I added firestore to my angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this error when I am trying to serve my app locally.

```
`Error: node_modules/rxfire/firestore/lite/interfaces.d.ts:8:29 - error 
TS2314: Generic type 'AggregateQuerySnapshot<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

```
export type CountSnapshot = lite.AggregateQuerySnapshot<{
count: lite.AggregateField<number>;
}, any, DocumentData>;`
```

I recently added `@angular/fire` using npm.

I already reinstalled node_modules but it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The error you're seeing indicates that there's a type mismatch or type expectation issue with the `AggregateQuerySnapshot` in the rxfire library , which is a dependency for `@angular/fire`.

You might be using versions of @angular/fire and Firebase that are incompatible with each other. As both libraries evolve, sometimes there are breaking changes or adjustments in their type definitions.

Try upgrading to the latest version of both packages. Or downgrading the individual packages to match. In this case, you could try installing a previous version of `rxfire`.

```
npm install rxfire@6.0.3
```

In my case, upgrading the firebase version to `v 10.3.1` did the trick for me.

`npm install firebase@latest @angular/fire@latest`

I hope this helps. Be sure to check the package's GitHub repo for updates and fixes.